# Call stored procedure with parameters using Web Api Odata

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, parameters, odata

Is it possible to call Stored Procedure with parameters using Web Api Odata?. How can I achieve that?. My intention is call Web APi Odata function with two parameters to get results I'am expecting. I was thinking about using "Views", but unfortunately i have to pass parameters to get more specific results. Thanks for advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose your stored procedure as an unbound OData function. An OData function is invoked using `GET` with the parameters specified in the URI. For example:

```
GET http://host/SomeFunction(Param1=123,AnotherParam='a string')
```

You will need to declare the function as part of your OData configuration, and write a controller action method to implement the stored procedure invocation. Here's a tutorial to get you started: [Actions and Functions in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions)